# How can I query from 2 dates ranges (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I want to pull the emails from 40 days ago and 20 days ago, each range being 1 day. This is what I have but it returns no rows.

```
SELECT s.*, r.email FROM sellyourcar s 
     INNER JOIN register r ON s.rid = r.slno 
     WHERE s.dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 20 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 19 DAY) AND 
     s.t BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 39 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an OR instead of and for your two intervals:

```
SELECT s.*, r.email 
FROM sellyourcar s INNER JOIN register r ON s.rid = r.slno 
WHERE s.dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 20 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 19 DAY) 
OR s.dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 40 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 39 DAY)
```

As another note, at least in Oracle, I am not sure about in MYSQL the BETWEEN functions returns items matching the end items also. For example between 3 and 5 would also return items that were 3 and 5 and not just 4. So you may want to just to check if the date of the email is 20  or 40 days less than the current date.

Comment: Yes, MySQL works the same w.r.t. BETWEEN.  This is part of standard SQL.

Comment: I thought so, but I was just not positive.